# Is the phrase "out of the box" an adjective or an adverb or an idiom?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Could someone explain the meaning of the phrase "out of the box"? Is it an adjective or an adverb or an idiom? Please point out its function in below sentences.

> For Python fans of Google’s Cloud SQL (currently available in limited preview), the long awaited out-of-the-box support for the Django framework has arrived and is now available as an experimental feature.
>
> Django 1.3 is not available on all Python runtimes out of the box

Comment: It’s not a word; it’s a phrase.  One can only call something a “word” if it has no spaces in it — I think.

Comment: Sure. I reworded all.

Comment: General Reference. Googling **define out of the box** gives a clear definition in the "snippet view" of the top result. Other than that, it's an idiomatic adjectival phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something can be used *out of the box*, it means it can be used easily without much further effort. In

> TeXworks has **out-of-the-box** support for synctex

*out-of-the-box* may be seen as an idiomatic adjective modifying the noun *support*. In

> TeXworks can be used **out of the box** with synctex

*out of the box* may be seen as an idiomatic adverbial phrase modifying the verb *used*.

Also note that *think out of the box* has another meaning altogether: to think in an unusual way.

Answer (score 3):

It means ready-to-go, without any complicated installation or assembly.

Have you ever bought something at the store, and you opened the carton, only to realize it would be at least an hour before you'd be able to use it?  That's called *some assembly required*, and it's the opposite of *out-of-the-box*.

For software, though, *out-of-the-box* refers to no complicated installations or configurations, as opposed to no physical assembly.

Reference: Meaning #2 at [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_the_box).